# is ServiceLocator, ConfigurationClass needed for implementing multilanguage on java application?

Tags: java, configuration, multilingual, service-locator

I am really not that experienced with these properties on making an application multilingual. I've got a main class, which will start my Login_View, where I should choose the language(english, german) within a combobox (javafx). When I choose a language, my application should update the view and it's text in the chosen language.
How can I implement this with a TranslatorClass efficiently? Is a ServiceLocator and ConfigurationClass needed?

Thx for helping

Answer (score -1):

Strongly suggest you to use resource files to implement multi-language UI Lables, Messages and so on. The active translator classes do not perform well and hard to translate words to eastern languages.  Service locator and Configuration Class do not need to be translated.